# I am unable to satisfy the constraints in the IOS 8 today extension

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, autolayout, ios8-today-widget

I almost gave up to solve the auto layout problems in my today extension :-(.

I have a simple today extension for my iOS 8 app, where I want to display a quadratic photo and two text labels.

Thank you for help.

[image]

This is my actual layout. The view is almost displayed correct in the simulator and on my real iPhone, but I couldn't eliminate the auto layout error messages.

```
2015-01-09 21:12:31.099  Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a379aa0 V:[UIButton:0x7a37a840'New Journal Entry'(38)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78f81680 UIButton:0x78f81310.width == 1.19111*UIButton:0x78f81310.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a1846f0 UILabel:0x7a37c770'12. Oktober 2014 06:22'.leading == UIView:0x7a1743c0.leadingMargin + 10>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a182580 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a175960]-(8)-[UILabel:0x7a37c770'12. Oktober 2014 06:22']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a185400 UIView:0x7a1743c0.trailingMargin == UIButton:0x78f81310.trailing + 10>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a17aff0 UIButton:0x78f81310.leading == UILabel:0x7a37c770'12. Oktober 2014 06:22'.leading>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a17b020 UIButton:0x78f81310.top == UILabel:0x7a37c770'12. Oktober 2014 06:22'.top + 29>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a17b9f0 V:[UIButton:0x78f81310]-(0)-[UIButton:0x7a37a840'New Journal Entry']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a17f780 V:[UIButton:0x7a37a840'New Journal Entry']-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a17b690]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7a179c70 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a175960(0)]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7a17ddf0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a175960]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7a1743c0 )>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7a17e0f0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a17b690(0)]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7a175000 _UILayoutGuide:0x7a17b690.bottom == UIView:0x7a1743c0.bottom>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78e4eee0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7a1743c0(273)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78e4eeb0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:    [UIView:0x7a1743c0(529)]>"
)
```

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug on Apple's side when it comes to autolayout for a today extension. I have literally zero autolayout constraints, it's turned off, yet I still get "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints".